# ReflectionTypeLoadException when loading external dll

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

Imagine I have a solution with some projects. In the project `Proj1.BL` I have the abstract class `MyAbstractClass`, and (*strong requirement*) I should inherit from it only in another solutions. All of them will contain only one class (e.g. `DerivedClass : MyAbstractClass`), will have references to corresponding projects from the first solution(`Proj1.BL`, `Proj1.DataModel`, etc.) and will be compiled to DLLs (Class Libraries). And in conclusion, these DLLs (*another strong requirement*) will be stored in `$(OutDir of first solution)\Externals`.

My question is: how should I load these assemblies within the first solution correctly? I've tried someway like this:

```
public static Type LoadType(string fileName)
{
    if (fileName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");

    fileName = Path.Combine("Externals", fileName);

    if (!File.Exists(fileName)) throw new ApplicationException("File does not exist.");

    return
        Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName)
                .GetTypes()
                .SingleOrDefault(_ => _.IsSubclassOf(typeof (MyAbstractClass)));
}
```

But I'm continuing to get

> **ReflectionTypeLoadException.** Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

`LoaderException` is about that CLR couldn't load type `Proj1.BL.MyAbstractClass` from `Proj1.BL, Version=*.*.*.*, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`.

*But code that I'm running is in `Proj1.BL`.* What's wrong?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eh, the answer was easily than expected. There was a version mismatch when `Proj1` assemblies' versions' values were autoincremented after each rebuild, but DLL expected to find `Proj1` assemblies' versions' that were specified at compile-time.